# BlackBerry: how to send messages (pin, mail, sms) to multiple subscribers automatically?

Tags: blackberry, mobile

I'm planning to do an BB app. But I don't know if it is possible. I ask for your recommendation.

It will consist of two apps.

- The **first**: the user will download it. He will be subscribed to the app, sharing his mobile number, PIN, and mail (could this be done automatically? This is, **without** the user typing that info and sending it)
- The **second**: the admin will send messages of different nature (sms, mail and/or pin) to the subscribers of the **first** app.

**Summarizing**: I would like to send messages (of different kind) to many users. I looked, and, at least, in the BB API is possible [to send mails](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Send_a_message_565449_11.jsp) to multiple users. But, how to do it with **sms** and **pin**.

Also, how would be the code logic that subscribe the users? Could be done automatically? If not, do I need a dedicated server to store the info of the users? etc.

If you have a more **elegant** way to achieve what I'm posting, please, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like one of your requirements is to originate the messages from a BlackBerry. This may be inefficient and costly.

The best solution to send data to multiple BlackBerry users is the Push Service which you can read about here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp

Comment: I will check it and share the tool with my colleges to see what they think. Thank you. (I will accept the answer when they tell me if the tool is OK! )